# VirtualBox: Disk in WinOS reporting ~1/3 actual space used by dynamically allocated disk

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I am hosting Windows 7 in VirtualBox. I am using a dynamically allocated disk. The actual size of the VDI file is reported as 85.7GB, however in the hosted Windows OS the total drive size is around 1/3 that, 30.4GB. The maximum size of the VDI is 200GB.

Comment: Yes during download extraction and installation of updates your drive expand, after cleaning up it does not contract again, it will continue to grow when needed until it reaches the 200GB limmit.

Comment: Ah... Ok. Is it due to begin fragmented or something? Is there anyway to prevent/reverse this? I want to limit the drive to 50GB rather than 200. Can I resize the VDI?

Comment: VirtualBox says, that dynamically allocated will only expand as needed; however, it will not shrink.

Comment: To shrink see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/444598/how-do-i-shrink-a-dynamically-growing-vdi-disk-from-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly not lightly.
What you can try is Clone your Windows7 and give it a smaller footprint, then when that works delete the old big one.
It is probably better to do an export appliance from the file menu, then create a new mashine with 50GB disk, and import the windows7 export here.