# Shrink too large VDI

Tags: server, virtualbox, gparted

[image]

So, I accidentally enlarged a 48GB .vhd disk to 120TB, instead of 120GB in Virtualbox. Realizing the error, I am now trying to bring it down to 120GB; however for obvious reason, `modifyvm --resize` is not working. See error in second image. Is there anything I can do to shrink my disk image to 120GB?

[image]
Resizing error

Comment: is your .vhd dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we can not "shrink" a virtual hard drive that we accidentally grew too much with using the `VBoxManage` command.

The only means of repair would be to create a new virtual drive of appropriate desired size and copy the data over.

Still, there is no harm done on creating such a huge drive as long as we do not actually partition and use it.

The drive is of dynamically growing type as only then we can resize it at all. **It will therefore not use any more physical space on the host drive than needed.** Unused virtual hard drive space will not use any physical space.

In case we had partitioned and used the additional space we may be able to  compact it again as [shown in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/444599/3940).