# Reducing Virtual Box Hard Disk

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, hard-drive

I have created virtual box hard disk for Ubuntu 16.04 system. I have dynamically allocated hard disk space of 8GB. After installation, the actual size is only around 3GB. My requirement is, now, I want to reduce 8GB space to 4GB because that is enough space. I need this because, I can create a 4GB image from VDI file and then can write this image to 4GB USB sticks. I am using **Virtual Box 5.0.24_Ubuntu r108355** and **Ubuntu 16.04.1**

**Note:** I have used VBoxManage command to modify hard disk:

```
# sudo VBoxManage modifyhd Ubuntu-16-04-1.vdi --resize 4096
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4)
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4)
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize medium operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

Basically I faced this problem :

**VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED**

**VBoxManage: error: Resize medium operation for this format is not implemented yet!**

**EDIT:** I wanted to reduce the Virtual Disk Size, not the VDI file itself. I want to make ISO image from VDI file, and shrinking basically did not help me, it was always 8GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi):

> The `--resize` x option ... currently works only for VDI and VHD formats, and only for the dynamically allocated variants, and can **only be used to expand (not shrink)** the capacity.

So it is not implemented to decrease the size of an existing virtual disk.

To physically shrink a dynamically allocated VDI see

- [How do I shrink a dynamically growing VDI disk from VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444598/how-do-i-shrink-a-dynamically-growing-vdi-disk-from-virtualbox)

In order to have a smaller logical virtual drive you need to copy the content to a newly created smaller drive.